# Controlling Form Submissions With Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I currently have a PHP file that contains a form which is built like the one below:

```
echo '<form action="sampleform.php" onSubmit="return verify()" method="post">';
echo '<p>1. Which of the following is a Walt Disney cartoon character?</p><ul><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" />&nbsp;<b>A.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Superman</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" />&nbsp;<b>B.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Batman</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" />&nbsp;<b>C.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Mickey Mouse</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" />&nbsp;<b>D.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Spiderman</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="?" checked style="display:none;" /></li></ul>';
echo '<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click ONCE when finished." /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /></form></div>';
```

This PHP file is built by attached a header file to it on loading. In that header file is the following script:

```
<script>
function verify(){
msg = "If you are sure you are finished, then select the OK button below. Otherwise, select the CANCEL button to return to the test.";
return confirm(msg);
}
</script>
```

Everything works now, except that students sometimes fail to read the prompt and prematurely end their testing session by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again before they are really done. What I need is a way to either modify the verify function or replace it with something that presents the student with two choices with the CANCEL choice being the default, and preventing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key from making the choice.

I've spent considerable time trying to figure out how to make options like `confirmOn` https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon to work, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a framework like bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
You can easily add options.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that you specified is a straight forward plugin.

For that plugin to work, make sure you have included **jquery plugin, jqueryui plugin, jqueryui css(not sure), and confirmon plugin.**

Then on the click of  a button, use this :

```
$('#myButton').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
  //now confirmed parameter can be TRUE or FALSE depending up on the user choice and you can do the same.
  if(confirmed) deleteSomethingImportant();
    else {
        //If we need to, we can do some actions here if the user cancelled the confirmation
    }
});
```

And in order to give your own title, use :

```
$('#myButton').confirmOn({
     questionText: 'This action cannot be undone, are you sure?',
     textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
     textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
},'click', function(e, confirmed) {
    if(confirmed) $(this).remove();
});
```

for changing the confirm on for submitting use this :

so if **mySubmit** is the id of the button to submit the **form** with id **myForm**, then you can use as :

```
$("#mySubmit").confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
  //now confirmed parameter can be TRUE or FALSE depending up on the user choice and you can do the same.
  e.preventDefault();//to stop default behavior of the submit
  if(confirmed) {
      //straight forward javascript code..
      $("#myForm").submit();
  };
    else {
        //If we need to, we can do some actions here if the user cancelled the confirmation
     return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I apparently did not make myself clear. What I am trying to figure out is how to use confirmOn in place of my current verify() function to control whether the form is submitted or not. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I added the code for that.. look into it once..
I think this time I got you right....

Comment: The mySubmit code seems to failing for some reason. I've placed two example files beginning at http://www.gensoup.org/confirmon/example1.html and I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: I noticed these in your code :
1) there is no event attached to your "mySubmit" id.
2) you have to stop the default behavior of the submit button using preventDefault method. 

I changed the code please look in to it once.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, described above, and have placed an example file at http://www.gensoup.org/confirmon/this_works.html if anyone is interested. The confirmon plugin allows me to control the Enter keypress to avoid premature form submission. Ankur Verma's replies helped me by pointing me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If it helped you then you should vote the answer up and accepts it.
:)
Just for curiosity 
:P